# How to flatten an array of arrays - but not all the way down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What's the best way to convert this

```
[[["Club three Team one", 7800], ["Club three Team two", 7801]], [], [["Club four Team one", 7807], ["Club four Team two", 7808]], []]
```

into

```
[["Club three Team one", 7800], ["Club three Team two", 7801], ["Club four Team one", 7807], ["Club four Team two", 7808]]
```

in ruby? flatten converts this all the way down to

```
["Club three Team one", 7303, "Club three Team two", 7304, "Club four Team one", 7310, "Club four Team two", 7311]
```

Answer (score 124, accepted):

use `flatten(1)` http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/flatten

```
your_array = [[["Club three Team one", 7800], ["Club three Team two", 7801]], [], [["Club four Team one", 7807], ["Club four Team two", 7808]], []]
your_array.flatten(1)
#=> [["Club three Team one", 7800], ["Club three Team two", 7801], ["Club four Team one", 7807], ["Club four Team two", 7808]]
```

Comment: it may be worth noting, for older Ruby versions: your_array.inject([], :concat)

Comment: @tokland for big arrays it would be much slower

Comment: @fl00r: Array#concat is in-place in Ruby, so it shouldn't be much slower. I made some tests and it's pretty much the same performance.

Comment: @tokland I think that `inject` is slowest part :)