# Create a nested hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, nested

I have an array like this:

```
[
  {:game_id=>546012, :period=>:fg, :stat_name=>:hits, :result=>12, :team_id=>1104}, 
  {:game_id=>546012, :period=>:fg, :stat_name=>:errors, :result=>1, :team_id=>1104}, 
  {:game_id=>546012, :period=>:fg, :stat_name=>:hits, :result=>9, :team_id=>1103}, 
  {:game_id=>546012, :period=>:fg, :stat_name=>:errors, :result=>3, :team_id=>1103}
]
```

How can turn it into an array of items like this:

```
{ 546012 => { :hits => { :fg => { 1104 => 12,  
                                  1103 => 9 } } 
              :errors => { :fg => { 1104 => 1,
                                  1103 => 3 } } }
```

Comment: Your expected result is not an array (of items).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 2):

First, create a hash organized by :game_id

```
{ 546012 => {{
  {:period=>:fg, :stat_name=>:hits, :result=>12, :team_id=>1104},
  {:period=>:fg, :stat_name=>:errors, :result=>1, :team_id=>1104},
  {:period=>:fg, :stat_name=>:hits, :result=>9, :team_id=>1103},
  {:period=>:fg, :stat_name=>:errors, :result=>3, :team_id=>1103}
]}
```

Then group by :stat_name

```
{ 546012 => [
  {:hits => [
     {:period=>:fg, :result=>12, :team_id=>1104},
     {:period=>:fg, :result=>9, :team_id=>1103}],
   :errors => [
     {:period=>:fg, :result=>1, :team_id=>1104},
     {:period=>:fg, :result=>3, :team_id=>1103}
   ]}
]}
```

Then group by period:

```
{ 546012 => [
  {:hits => [
     :fg => [{:result=>12, :team_id=>1104},
       {:result=>9, :team_id=>1103}]
     ]}
   ]},
   :errors => [
     :fg => [{:result=>1, :team_id=>1104},
       {:result=>3, :team_id=>1103}]
   ]}
]}
```

Lastly, group by :team_id and associate each one to its :result.

```
{ 546012 => [
  {:hits => [
     :fg => [1104 => 12, 1103 => 9]
   ]},
   :errors => [
     :fg => [1104 => 1, 1103 => 3]
   ]}
]}
```

As for how to create these groupings, I will leave it as an exercise to you.

One possible method is to loop through each item and create a new copy of the object that stores these new mappings.  For instance, if we have this object:

```
foods = {
  {:food => lemon, :taste => sour},
  {:food => pretzel, :taste => salty},
  {:food => pretzel, :taste => sweet}
}
```

We could group by foods like (pseudocode):

```
newfoods = {};
foreach item in foods:
   newfoods[ item.food ].push( item.taste );
```

And end up with

```
newfoods = [
  { lemon => [sour] },
  { pretzel => [sweet, salty] }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The best option you can do is [flatten](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/flatten) it.

Credits go to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612625/how-to-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-but-not-all-the-way-down).