# ruby convert multidimensional array into one array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multidimensional-array, flatten

I've merged 2 lists.

```
list1 = customer.links.where(ext: true).group(:link_id, :external).limit(100).order('count_id desc').count('id') 
list2 = customer.links.where(ext: false).where.not(url: '/specific_link').group(:url, :ext).limit(100).order('count_id desc').count('id')

list = list1.merge(list2).sort_by{|k, v| -v}
```

The result is:

```
[[["/path/element1", false], 7], [[4, true], 5], [["/path/element6", false], 1]]
```

I want to convert it into a on dimensional hash, like that:

```
[["/path/element1", false, 7], [4, true, 5], ["/path/element6", false, 1]]
```

When I use `flatten`, there is no separation between the arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
arr = [[["/path/element1", false], 7], [[4, true], 5], [["/path/element6", false], 1]]
arr.map { |k,v| [*k,v] }
#=> [["/path/element1", false, 7], [4, true, 5], ["/path/element6", false, 1]]
```

Comment: @@sagarpandya82 beat me to it.

Comment: No, we have different answers!

Comment: And this is te perfect answer for my problem. Thank you

Comment: @RickySpanish updated with a possibly better way, take a look.

Comment: @RickySpanish removed alternative, as Anuj has already posted, it's actually the better solution so  I'd accept that answer.

Answer (score 8):

Easy and simple do flatten to each sub array.

```
output_array=[[["/path/element1", false], 7], [[4, true], 5], [["/path/element6", false], 1]].map{|x| x.flatten}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Ruby flatten method](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/flatten).

```
[[["/path/element1", false], 7], [[4, true], 5], [["/path/element6", false], 1]].flatten(1)

result => [["/path/element1", false], 7, [4, true], 5, ["/path/element6", false], 1]
```

Also posted here in this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612625/how-to-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-but-not-all-the-way-down).

Update below to at least make this correct (like the other answers).
To flatten a level deeper, you can use .map to flatten the lower arrays.

```
[[["/path/element1", false], 7], [[4, true], 5], [["/path/element6", false], 1]].map {|x| x.flatten }

result => [["/path/element1", false, 7], [4, true, 5], ["/path/element6", false, 1]]
```